# I get "Release of profile requested but WebEnginePage still not deleted. Expect troubles !" even after calling app.exec()

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qwebengineview, qapplication

I have a python code like below

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtWebEngineWidgets
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QNetworkCookie
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPageLayout, QPageSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
import argparse

def main(app):
    url = ''
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Just an example", formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument("--url", help="Type url")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    config = vars(args)
    url = config['url']

    loader = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView()
    profile = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineProfile("storage", loader)
    cookie_store = profile.cookieStore()

    with open('cookie.txt', 'rb') as f:
        contents = f.read()

    cookie_store.setCookie(QNetworkCookie(contents))
    webpage = QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEnginePage(profile, loader)
    COOKIPATH = "./Cache" + str(1)
    # web_profile.setCachePath(COOKIPATH)
    profile.setPersistentStoragePath(COOKIPATH)
    profile.setPersistentCookiesPolicy(2)
    loader.setPage(webpage)
    loader.setZoomFactor(1)
    layout = QPageLayout()
    layout.setPageSize(QPageSize(QPageSize.A4Extra))
    layout.setOrientation(QPageLayout.Portrait)
    loader.load(QUrl(url))
    loader.page().pdfPrintingFinished.connect(lambda *args: QApplication.exit())

    def emit_pdf(finished):
        QTimer.singleShot(2000, lambda: loader.page().printToPdf("test.pdf", pageLayout=layout))


    loader.loadFinished.connect(emit_pdf)
    app.exec()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main(app)
```

I run above code like this `python3 htmlToPdfnew.py --url http://example.com`

but when I run the code I get a warning like below

```
Release of profile requested but WebEnginePage still not deleted. Expect troubles !
```

based on suggestions I got from internet calling `app.exec()`

but still get that error

how to resolve that error ?

Comment: You get that "error", but, most importantly, does the program run successfully?

Comment: @musicamante yes. I get the correct output

Comment: Then, you probably don't need to worry to much. Besides, try removing the `main()` entirely, and move everything in the `if __name__` block, which might solve some context issues related to that warning.